# IllegalStateException got on play console

Tags: android, build.gradle, illegalstateexception, runtimeexception

we uploaded android application on production and we encountered one issue and we are unable to solve it.can anyone please help with this?

i don't have any idea about this error.but my app is continuously crashing on users devices.and the thing is i cant able to reproduce that error on available devices.

```
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.plattysoft.leonids:LeonidsLib:1.3.1'
compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.4'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta2'
```

stack trace:=
  `java.lang.RuntimeException:`

`at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3624)`

`at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:240)`

`at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1808)`

`at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)`

`at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)`

`at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7081)`

`at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)`

`at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)`

`at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:`

`at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1666)`

`at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1611)`

`at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:677)`

`at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:677)`

`at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService
(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:89)`

`at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzh (UnknownSource:11)`

`at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzb (Unknown Source:72)`

`at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source:25)`

`at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3615)`

Comment: Please add error log, without that we can't help.

Comment: error log is in stack trace which is at the below of gradle code.please check

Comment: WakefulBroadcastReceiver is part of an android library

Comment: any particular android OS  version for which you are getting this error. It seems like a problem with oreo and greater than oreo os version.

Comment: yes , it is specifically crashing on android versions 8.0 and greater.

Comment: Google has made some changes from oreo. You are using WakefulBroadcastReceiver which is deprecated. As mentioned in android documentation _As of Android O, background check restrictions make this class no longer generally useful. (It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so.) Instead, developers should use android.app.job.JobScheduler to schedule a job_

Comment: OK ,thank you Amit, I'll try to do it.

Comment: @AmitTiwary but is it possible that this error can crash our app? i'm asking because i test many times on these versions and i'm not getting any crashes on that devices.

Comment: It's not easy to replicate this error. If you show your code then I can guide you to replicate the error.